# Manipulación del DOM con angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, ionic3

Tengo problemas para manipular el DOM con angular 5

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es agarrar la etiqueta p con

```
#minu y @ViewChild('minu') minu ;
```

pero al hacer console.log(this.minu) el resultado que obtengo es

```
[object object]
```

en vez de la etiqueta

tambien intente obtener la etiqueta con document.getElementsByClassName('.minutes')

pero al imprimir esto por console.log me da undefiend

```js
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2} from "@angular/core";
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from "ionic-angular";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: "page-cvv-code",
  templateUrl: "cvv-code.html",
})
export class CvvCodePage {
  @ViewChild('minu') minu ;


  minutes:any
  seconds:any
  cont = 0;
  //

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.timer();
  }

timer(){

     let display = this.minu


     let txt = this.renderer.createText('03:00 Min');
     this.renderer.appendChild(display, 'ssdsdsdsa')

    let threeMinutes = 60 * 3;
      let timer = 180;
      let minutes 
      let seconds      

      let i = setInterval(function () {

       let  m = timer / 60
       let s = timer % 60
        
        minutes = parseInt( m.toString(), 10);
        seconds = parseInt(s.toString(), 10);
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
         display.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds + ' Min';
        
        console.log(minutes + ':' + seconds + ' Min');
        
        

        if (--timer < 0) {
            clearInterval(i)
          timer = threeMinutes;
          
        }

      }, 1000);
  }


}
```

```html
<p class="minutes" #minu></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

LLama el método `timer()` en el  `ngAfterViewInit()`:

```
ngAfterViewInit()
{ 
  this.timer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Su problema puede resolverse de la siguiente manera:

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef,AfterViewInit, Renderer2} from "@angular/core";
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from "ionic-angular";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: "page-cvv-code",
  templateUrl: "cvv-code.html",
})
export class CvvCodePage implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('minu') minu: ElementRef; 


  minutes:any
  seconds:any
  cont = 0;
  //

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private renderer: Renderer2) {
    // this.timer();

  }

ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Check in the console log the current value
    console.log(this.minu.nativeElement.innerHTML); 

  //  this.minu.nativeElement.innerHTML = "Valor DOM actualizado correctamente!!!"; 
     timer();
  }

timer(){

     let display = this.minu


     let txt = this.renderer.createText('03:00 Min');
     this.renderer.appendChild(display, 'ssdsdsdsa')

    let threeMinutes = 60 * 3;
      let timer = 180;
      let minutes 
      let seconds      

      let i = setInterval(function () {

       let  m = timer / 60
       let s = timer % 60

        minutes = parseInt( m.toString(), 10);
        seconds = parseInt(s.toString(), 10);
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
         display.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds + ' Min';

        console.log(minutes + ':' + seconds + ' Min');



        if (--timer < 0) {
            clearInterval(i)
          timer = threeMinutes;

        }

      }, 1000);
  }


}
```

En el metodo ngAfterViewInit() accede y  modifica los elementos nativos del DOM usando el nativeElement del objeto minu: